# Como verifico se o objeto tem uma string de nome especifo em ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, react

Quero renderizar uma imagem apenas se meu objeto tiver a propriedade "happy", então jogar a imagem que quero apenas se for este a string. Meu objeto é uma API
Exemplo:

```
api = {
 type: "happy"
}
someFunction(){
  return({api.type[0] === "happy"? (<img src={happy.png} />) : (<img src{sad.png}/>)"})
}
```

Comment: A propriedade (chave) ou o valor `"happy"`? O que deu a entender da sua pergunta foi se um objeto tem algo como `{ happy: "algum valor..." }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente não utilizar valores soltos para comparações desse tipo, armazene em um constante. É importante também se atentar como está o fluxo de dados entre os componentes, priorize o HoC (Higher-Order Component).

```
const TYPE_HAPPY = "happy";

const ImageHappyOrSad = ({ type }) =>
  type === TYPE_HAPPY ? <img src={happy.png} /> : <img src={sad.png} />;

const App = () => {
  const api = {
    type: "happy",
  };

  return <ImageHappyOrSad type={api.type} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você já está recebendo o atributo `type` diretamente do seu objeto `api` basta você na sua função realizar

```
someFunction(){
  return({api.type === "happy"? (<img src={happy.png} />) : (<img src{sad.png}/>)"})
}
```

Visto que você possui apenas um objeto do tipo `api` e o seu atributo `type` não é nenhum array de objeto não tem a necessidade de você acessar o `type[0]`